# count sequence of "1,2,3" in c++

Tags: c++

I have to count the number of sequences of 1,2,3 in an array, like this:

Example:

```
input: [1,2,3,1,2,2,3]
output: 2
```

Another one:

```
input[1,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,3]
output: 2
```

My code (which isn't working):

```
int correctNumber= 1;
    int occurrence= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (vector[i] > correctNumber){
            correctNumber= 1;


        if (vector[i] == correctNumber|| vector[i] == (correctNumber+ 1))
        {


            if (vector[i] == (correctNumber+ 1)){
                correctNumber++;

            }
            if (vector[i] == 3 && vector[i + 1] != 3){
                correctNumber= 1;
                occurrences++;
            }



        }}
    }
```

Comment: _My code isn't working_ is hardly a question. What are your results, and what do you expect the results to be?

Comment: Let me rephrase it for you: why isn't it working?

Comment: Here’s a hint: the behavior of your program should change based on its state, where its state is one of: no sequence in progress, found 1, found 2, found 3, end.

Comment: I get it. I think i could use switch(option), being the option the number 'for' is on.

Comment: @Paul Strange response to Tas's comment. This question is actually off-topic according to the site's rules. What happens when you run your program? Does it crash? Does it run forever without giving an answer? Does it give the wrong answer?

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thanks for the replies, i'll make sure my next question is more elaborated.

Comment: @Paul By the way, what Lorehead was describing is a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Comment: Never heard of that before, definitely will take a look into it.

Comment: @Paul If you managed to get it working now, consider to post an answer that describes how you managed exactly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With `std::find`:

```
std::size_t count_123(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); )
    {
        it = std::find(it, v.end(), 1);
        it = std::find(it, v.end(), 2);
        it = std::find(it, v.end(), 3);
        if (it != v.end()) {
            ++res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mPv1Xr)

Comment: @Svalorzen: I expect `1` as answer.